# Trying to instantiate named(annotated) classes

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, guice, playframework-2.4, named

First of all, thanks for any effort to try and answer the question.
From the current application injector (play.api.Play.current.injector), how do I get a Named instance of a class?
I tried to cast the injector to a ScalaInjector (net.codingwell.scalaguice.InjectorExtensions.ScalaInjector) and to Guice Injector (com.google.inject.Injector), both unsuccessful.
The problem is that there are only 3 methods to instantiate a class, all of them are overloaded instanceOf[T]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a normal dependency you would do

```
play.api.Play.current.injector.instanceOf[ProjectRepo]
```

When you want to retrieve a named dependency you can do

```
val qualifier = Some(QualifierInstance(Names.named("name")))
val bindingKey = BindingKey[ProjectRepo](Class[ProjectRepo], qualifier)

play.api.Play.current.injector.instanceOf[ProjectRepo](bindingKey)
```

Anyway you should only use the injector directly in very rare cases, makes sure there is not a simpler way to retrieve your dependencies.

Comment: It's for tests basically, so I can get the object before and set the test attributes.

Comment: If all you want to do is mock some dependencies you can follow https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice#Overriding-bindings-in-a-functional-test

Comment: Your question is very specific about obtaining a Named instance using the injector, current the answer is just about that.

Answer (score 3):

When you need to inject a named dependency (in my case an ActorRef) you can also use a case class to help:

```
case class NamedActorHelper @Inject() (@Named("some-actor") actor: ActorRef)

class SomeActorSpec with GuiceOneAppPerSuite {
  ...
  val someActor = app.injector.instanceOf[NamedActorHelper].actor
  ...
}
```

Replacing *app* with *play.api.Play.current* should also work.